# How to figure out time complexity for a while loop nested in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

So I have this code here and I am just trying to understand the time and space complexity.

for time complexity I think its O(n^2) because it is going through at most n - 1 loops in the while loop and it will go through n times in the for loop so it will be O(n(n-1)) which is O(n^2) and space complexity I think its O(n) because it is linear space.

I don't know if I'm right but if I am wrong can someone correct my thinking? Thanks in advance.

```
    // Write your code here
    let visited = new Array(s.length).fill(false);
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        let j = i + 1;
        visited[i] = true;
        while (j < s.length && s[j] === s[i] && !visited[j]) {
            visited[j] = true;
            count++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: whta is the purpose of it? do you have some data and result?

Comment: @NinaScholz its just a hacker rank question I solved so I'm trying to figure out time and space complexity for interview prep

Comment: @user1599011 it can run for the length of s because s can have the same letter for the whole string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `O(n)` in time complexity, because:

```
while (j < s.length && s[j] === s[i] && !visited[j]) {
```

For this condition to be fulfilled, `visited[j]` needs to be false, and when it does get fulfilled, you then do

```
visited[j] = true;
```

So, that above line can only run as many times as there are items in the `visited` array. If the `while` loop runs to the end the *first* outer iteration (when `i` is 0), then it'll never run in any of the other outer iterations. If the `while` loop runs halfway through `visited` the first iteration, and through the other half the second iteration, it'll never run for the rest of the outer iterations. So, this part of the code:

```
    while (j < s.length && s[j] === s[i] && !visited[j]) {
        visited[j] = true;
        count++;
        j++;
    }
```

will never run more than `visited.length` times total.

The outer loop is, of course, `O(n)`. So, you get

```
outer loop: O(n)
+ inner loop: O(n) when summed over all iterations of the outer loop
= O(n)
```

Comment: but j gets incremented each time so it can run for the whole length of s if s[j] === s[i] is always true

Comment: If it runs for the whole length the first time - when `i` is 0 - then it won't run for any of the other `i`s. Over the entire function call, the `while` loop will, in total, run no more than `s.length` times.

Comment: ahh that makes a lot of sense.. no wonder my algorithm ran pretty fast even though s could've been as large as 100k. THANK YOU!